# Disable generateSources during Gradle sync

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

When I sync dependencies with Gradle in Android Studio, a `generateSources` task is kicked off on all of my included modules. This is really slow and most of the time doesn't have a material impact on what I'm trying to do. Is there a way to disable generateSources so that it no longer runs automatically?